# I am trying to make a final grade calculator in mips, but it is not working

Tags: assembly, mips

I am stuck on this program, I am trying to input curve and grade add them together and output whether the student got an a b, c, d or f. It is not working and I don't know what I am missing. Please let me know what I am doing wrong here or if I am missing something. My final output prints "You got an A+"You got an A"You got an B+"You got an B"You got an C+"You got an C"You got an D"

```
.data

STR_MESSAGE1: .asciiz "Enter the grade: "
STR_MESSAGE2: .asciiz "Enter the curve: "
GRADEAPLUS: .asciiz "You earned A+"
GRADEA: .asciiz "You earned A"
GRADEBPLUS: .asciiz "You earned B+"
GRADEB: .asciiz "You earned B"
GRADECPLUS: .asciiz "You earned C+"
GRADEC: .asciiz "You earned C"
GRADEDPLUS: .asciiz "You earned D+"
GRADED: .asciiz "You earned D"
GRADEF: .asciiz "You earned F"
NEW_LINE:    .asciiz "\n"

.text
.globl main




main:
    # set the parameters #########################
    li     $t0, 0              # set "zero" to $t0 register
    li     $t1, 0              # set "zero" to $t1 register
    li     $t2, 100             # loop counter
    li     $t3, 2             # loop counter
    li     $t4, 8              # set "one" to $t1 register
    li     $t5, 0


curve_check:
    li    $v0, 4                   # system call no. 4
    la    $a0, STR_MESSAGE2        # point to the message
    syscall
    li    $v0, 5                   # system call no. 5
    syscall                    
    blt   $v0, $t3, curve_check    # check value in in $v0 register less than 2
    bgt   $v0, $t4, curve_check    # check value in in $v0 register greater than 8
    move  $v0, $t1

grade_check:

    # print the text message #####################
    li     $v0, 4                   # system call no. 4
    la     $a0, STR_MESSAGE1        # point to the message
    syscall
    li     $v0, 5                   # system call no. 5
    syscall                         # do it!
    bltzal $v0, grade_check         # check value in in $v0 register less than 0
    bgt   $v0, $t2, grade_check    # check value in in $v0 register greater than 100
    move $v0, $t0              # copy value from $v0 register to $t0 register

score_add:
    addu    $t5, $t0, $t1      
    bge $t5, 95, grade_a_plus
    bge $t5, 90, grade_a
    bge $t5, 85, grade_b_plus
    jr $31

.end main

grade_a_plus:
    li     $v0, 4                   # system call no. 4
    la     $a0, GRADEAPLUS        # point to the message
    syscall


grade_a:
    li     $v0, 4                   # system call no. 4
    la     $a0, GRADEA        # point to the message
    syscall


grade_b_plus:
    li     $v0, 4                   # system call no. 4
    la     $a0, GRADEBPLUS        # point to the message
    syscall


grade_b:
    li     $v0, 4                   # system call no. 4
    la     $a0, GRADEB        # point to the message
    syscall


grade_c_plus:
    li     $v0, 4                   # system call no. 4
    la     $a0, GRADECPLUS        # point to the message
    syscall


grade_d_plus:
    li     $v0, 4                   # system call no. 4
    la     $a0, GRADEDPLUS        # point to the message
    syscall


grade_d:
    li     $v0, 4                   # system call no. 4
    la     $a0, GRADED        # point to the message
    syscall


grade_f:
    li     $v0, 4                   # system call no. 4
    la     $a0, GRADEF        # point to the message
    syscall
```

Comment: Use the simulator to single step debug.  Verify each instruction: the state of the program between instructions, and the next instruction to run.  When some instruction doesn't do as you expect, the revisit that.

Comment: Let's note that the processor never sees labels, the assembler removes them from the machine code.  The labels are assigned code or data address values, and the assembler (and linker as needed) uses those address values to compute the fields needed in instructions and data that reference/use those labels.  By the time the processor is executing machine code, all it sees are machine code instructions with proper immediate values when labels have been referenced.  Otherwise, it does not see labels at all.